# Can we customize default action bar(built in) in navigation activity

Tags: android-studio, user-interface, android-actionbar, toolbar

When I change Dark Action Bar to No Action Bar from styles my app do not open, what can I do, please suggest me some ways.

Comment: add your code and logcat error so that people can see what you have done, from this line  I can only suggest you check app bar uses because a navigation activity use the app bar to toggle navigation gravity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove your activity action bar then try this instead of NoActionBar styles

Write this in your activity OnCreate()

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();

}
```

and also remove your Menifest noActionbar lines which gives the error.

Hope this works !!!